# How to get the difference between rows

Tags: python, pandas

This is my DataFrame:

```
utc_timestamp               data
2015-10-13 11:00:00+00:00   1
2015-10-13 12:00:00+00:00   5
2015-10-13 13:00:00+00:00   6
2015-10-13 14:00:00+00:00   10
2015-10-13 15:00:00+00:00   11
```

The values of `data` are cumulative.

How can I get this result:

```
utc_timestamp               data
2015-10-13 11:00:00+00:00   1
2015-10-13 12:00:00+00:00   4
2015-10-13 13:00:00+00:00   1
2015-10-13 14:00:00+00:00   4
2015-10-13 15:00:00+00:00   1
```

I know that it's possible to use `df["data"].diff()`, but how can I get the complete final `df` with `utc_timestamp`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need `fillna`:

```
df['data'] = df['data'].diff(1).fillna(df['data'])
```

Or use `shift` with `fill_value` option so as you don't downcast your data to float:

```
df['data'] -= df['data'].shift(fill_value=0)
```

Output:

```
               utc_timestamp  data
0  2015-10-13 11:00:00+00:00     1
1  2015-10-13 12:00:00+00:00     4
2  2015-10-13 13:00:00+00:00     1
3  2015-10-13 14:00:00+00:00     4
4  2015-10-13 15:00:00+00:00     1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try assign it back

```
df['data'] = df['data'].diff()
```